# How to add styles using styled-components to programatically created heading with dynamic level?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I would like to add styles to `<h1>`, `<h2>`, ... elements created using the following code.

I am using [react-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown) to parse markdown and generate HTML using React.

I know about the `styled.h1` and `styled(component)` syntax, but both require having a hard coded style or component ahead of time.

```
interface HeadingProps {
  level: number
  children: JSX.Element[]
}

class Heading extends Component<HeadingProps> {
  constructor(props: HeadingProps) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return React.createElement(
      `h${this.props.level}`,
      {
        className: "react-cms-heading",
      },
      <Fragment>
        {this.props.children}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

<ReactMarkdown
  source={story.content}
  renderers={{
    heading: (headingProps) => {
      return (
        <Heading level={headingProps.level}>
          {headingProps.children}
        </Heading>
      )
    }
  }}
/>
```

The following works, but I am trying to avoid using `createGlobalStyle` inside of components (and `className` in general).

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  .react-cms-heading {
    position: relative;
  }
`
```

Comment: Please show full example of what you trying to achieve, are you trying creating a styled component after you have this `h1` component?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your styles ahead as normal:

```
// same style as className
const Styled = styled.div’...’
```

Then use “as” prop for dynamicly change the element:

```
<Styled as={level}>{children}<\Styled>
```

*answered from a phone, would edit later